# How to use fragments with tables in reveal js?

Tags: reveal.js, presentation

I use markdown to write a presentation in reveal js. Now i have a big table which i want to get visible incrementally. I thought to use fragments like this:

```
Example 1|Example 2|
|:---:|:---:|
|row 1 1|row 1 2| <!-- .element: class="fragment" -->
|row 2 1|row 2 2| <!-- .element: class="fragment" -->
```

which doesnt work. Does someone have a solution for this?

Edit: I found it out; use HTML:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Example 1</th>
      <th>Example 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="fragment">
      <td>row 1 1</td>
      <td>row 1 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr fragment>
      <td>row 2 1</td>
      <td>row 2 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```